# "SQL Network Interfaces Error: 50" in Visual Studio IDE

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to create database file and configure datasource by right clicking on **SqlDataSource** in Visual Studio IDE:

[image]

Then I give a name for the database file and when I hit ok I get an error message like this:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
>
> The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>
> (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Error occurred during LocalDB instance startup: SQL Server process failed to start.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried hitting `Browse...` and picking a location to create the file in?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error)

Comment: @NPras I have browse it and create in app data folder...